# Convert the PDF file to Excel or XML file without much coding with same format in PDF in Python programming

Tags: python

All the Anaconda pypdf2 or pdfrw or pdfminer3k or reportlab support to extract the metadata of the metadata of the file and extract only the text content for the PDF to Text file or Excel file, But actual issue is need to convert the PDF file to a Excel file with and changes in the formatting like(Tables, text box information embedded) in the PDF. Any one support this issue to with any of your support documents.

Tried using all the modules available in Anaconda Cloud pypdf2 or pdfrw or pdfminer3k or reportlab

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you tried and issues you observed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the kind of thing that can be done "without much coding", considering the near endless amount of ways data can be communicated as a table in a PDF.

Unless you want to get into the PDF Spec and get your hands in there, your best bet will most likely be to use some sort of an API that provides this functionality (PdfTables has one I believe), or something similar to [Tabula](https://tabula.technology/) (this also has a Python binding), which you could use to extract the tables and then manually generate the XLSX files through something like Openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

Note that tables are one of the most difficult things to parse from PDFs due to their relational and structural variety, so you might struggle to find an easy solution for this.

I would suggest you look into the python GROBID library (https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has been found to be particularly efficient to parse PDFs into XML/TEI encoded format. Once encoded in xml format I would highly recommend you this tool to transform tables into sql objects: https://github.com/nikolamilosevic86/TableDisentangler